# Filtering ssrs hide values

Tags: reporting-services, filtering, ssrs-2012

I added filter into row group like:

[image]

But for some reason it hides values more than 0, so in report I show separate values and then sum of all but for some reason filter hides that columns for example:

[image]

it will throw more registers to complete 11 (when I remove filter) I can show them. What am I doing wrong?

Expression: `=iif(IsNothing(Fields!nPeriodo.Value > CINT(replace(left(Split(Parameters!DimTiempoMes.Value,"[").GetValue(3),2),"]",""))),0 ,Sum(Fields!PPMS_PPM.Value))`

Answer (score 0):

I solve it. Just added a Sum to Filter expression like:

```
=Sum([PPMS_PPM])
```